# Sort data frame by values of character string in column in R

Tags: r, sorting

I have dataset like this:

```
    term                occ    value 
Less Than 1 year        Yale     1
Less Than 1 year        MIT      3
1 Year                  Yale     2
2 Years                 Yale     3
2 Years                 Yale     8
2 years                 CMU      2
3 Years                 Yale     5
3 years                 NYU      2
Greater than 3 Years    NYU      5
Greater Than 3 Years    CALTEC   4
No Fixed Term           Yale     2
Other                   Bu       9
```

I want a table shows counts of the numbers of records by Term. And table should be in order of Term.

NOTE: The difference between "Years" and "years", "Than" and "than".

The output is like this:

```
term                count
Less Than 1 year      2
1 Year                1
2 Years               3
3 Years               2
Greater than 3 Years  2
No Fixed Term         1
Other                 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a special order, you need to specify the order of the levels in the factor. Also you need to do comparisons without regard for the case. This should work

```
# reproducible data
dd<-read.table(text="term,occ,value 
Less Than 1 year,Yale,1
Less Than 1 year,MIT,3
1 Year,Yale,2
2 Years,Yale,3
2 Years,Yale,8
2 years,CMU,2
3 Years,Yale,5
3 years,NYU,2
Greater than 3 Years,NYU,5
Greater Than 3 Years,CALTEC,4
No Fixed Term,Yale,2
Other,Bu,9", header=T, sep=",")

# specify custom order

termorder<-c("Less Than 1 year","1 Year","2 Years","3 Years",
    "Greater than 3 Years","No Fixed Term","Other")

#tabulate
tt <- table(factor(tolower(dd$term), levels=tolower(termorder), labels=termorder))
```

that returns a named vector. if you want a data.frame you can do

```
as.data.frame(tt)
#                 Var1 Freq
# 1     Less Than 1 year    2
# 2               1 Year    1
# 3              2 Years    3
# 4              3 Years    2
# 5 Greater than 3 Years    2
# 6        No Fixed Term    1
# 7                Other    1
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `table` after converting the 'term' to all `lower` or `upper` case

```
as.data.frame(table(tolower(df1$term)))
```

If we need a custom order, then we need to convert it to `factor` with `levels` specified before doing the `table`

---

Or instead of using the `tolower`, we can also replace the words with `sub`

```
v1 <- sub("Than", "than", sub("years", "Years", df1$term))
as.data.frame(table(factor(v1, levels = unique(v1))))
#                  Var1 Freq
#1     Less than 1 year    2
#2               1 Year    1
#3              2 Years    3
#4              3 Years    2
#5 Greater than 3 Years    2
#6        No Fixed Term    1
#7                Other    1
```

Comment: But there are difference between "Years" and "years", etc. See my NOTE part. And how to order them, not just show the counts.

Comment: @WhiteBig I did change it to `tolower`.  Regarding the `order` part it looks like a custom order.   So, it needs to be converted to `factor` with `levels` specified in that order before doing the `order`

Comment: I'll give a shot, and we'll see.